# Taking a loan from yourself

Tags: credit-card, debt, salary

In general everyone is, for good reason, against having credit card debt. 
In a scenario where someone is paid a certain sum each month, and wants to spend only a certain amount each month, can he spend more and then take it out of next month's payment?
In other words, is there any problem with using oneself as a "credit card" or sorts?
Is it just that it can cause bad habits?

Comment: can you elaborate more. So if you are paid 100 every month, you plan to spend only 60 every month. And in a given month spend 70 and then next month restrict to 50?

Comment: @Dheer that is correct

Comment: @andrewmh20 what is the difference with using credit card here?

Comment: @oldergod I'm spending my money, not going into debt.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Using Dheer example, since you earn 100 but save 30 from it, can we say you earn only 70 a month? Then if you spend 80, 10 over your earning's limit, and intend to let your future self pay for the extra 10, cannot we say your are going into debt? What is then the real difference between loaning money from you or from the bank if your future self will either way, have to pay for it?

Comment: @oldergod correct --thats basically what I am asking. Is there a difference, such that this would be okay but cc debt no. The possible difference I see is that I'm never at risk of not being able to pay a loan to someone else, just perhaps take a little more money out of my savings account one month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is called following (or going over) a budget. There is no debt or loans in the scenario you are describing.

Simply put a budget is when you allocate a certain amount of your income for expenses in various categories, and a certain amount for savings.

So lets say you earn $100 a month. If you budget $50 in expenses every month, then that means you try not to spend more then $50 a month, and the rest you save. In any given month, you may go over your self-imposed budgeted amount for expenses. That simply means you are over the budgetted amount for that month, but that does not make you 'in debt'. It just means you didn't meet your goal for that month (or whatever time period you created). However, if you do this habitually then you clearly don't have a realistic budget, because the idea behind a budget is a plan that you can realistically meet on a consistent basis. Sometimes you may have to break it, but it should be made in such a way that if you work at it, it is consistently achievable. If not, then you need to rethink your budget.

Instead of thinking in terms of taking loans from yourself, I would encourage you to think in terms of saving up for goals and only spending money from those 'goal funds.' In this way, you are not arbitrarily spending money that would instead go into savings, but rather explicitly setting money aside for those goals. This will also help you to see where exactly your money is going and also help you to prioritize your financial goals.

Comment: If you insist on taking loans from yourself, set up a savings category that you will take loans from, and _only_ take loans from that, and follow the rule that you can't borrow more than is in that fund. This turns it into a savings plan rather than a borrowing plan; you're just saving for flexible purchasing rather than for something specific.

Answer (score 3):

> someone is paid a certain sum each month, and wants to spend only a certain amount each month, can he spend more and then take it out of next month's payment?

Using the example 100 month 1, 60 first month. Save 40
Second Month, 100 salary, spend 70. Save 30. Overall Savings 70
Third month, 100 salary, spend 50. Save 50. Overall Savings 120

So in short term or once a while doing this is fine. However if [and this depends on individuals] it goes beyond control, i.e. you keep spending say 90 every month, you would have to save for quite a few months to get back to normal.

A better way would be to reverse this.
Using the example 100 month 1, 60 first month. Save 40
Second Month, 100 salary, spend 50. Save 50. Overall Savings 90
Third month, 100 salary, spend 70. Save 30. Overall Savings 120

i.e. save more first and then spend, rather than spending now and saying you will save in future. Generally this is the trap quite a few fall into specially when saving for retirement, they keep putting it to future and very soon realize that they can't get back to the goal.